# Gitlab push/pull: Git asks for password of user git

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, gitlab

I set up SSH Keys on my Windows Machine and then I added the key in my gitlab account according to the setup guide: [Gitlab SSH KEY](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html)

But I ran into an issue:
When I try to test the connection with *ssh -T* I am promt to provide the password for the user git, which I do not know. I haven't set a password for the key.

```
$ ssh -T git@mygitlab.com -p 8922
git@mygitlab.com's password:
```

I also tried to execute the command as sudo/admin

### Update

I also wrote a config file (.ssh/config) to specify which key should be used but it did not work. Now this rises a question on the GitLab side since I host an instance of my own. Is there some special setting I haven't set up correctly? Or do I have to reconfigure the user *git* ?

I think I forgot to mention that I host my own instance of gitlab and I'm missing a configuration [Admin Setup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/ssh_certificates.html#why-use-openssh-certificates) but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Can somebody please share their knowledge of their gitlab.rb file?

Comment: Looks like your ssh client doesn't realize you want to use that new ssh private key for `mygitlab.com`, so it offered your default private key and was rejected, and it fell back to asking for the remote user's password.  You can pass the path to your new ssh private key on the command line or configure your `~/.ssh/config` file to automatically choose the file for `mygitlab.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not using the correct ssh command to access via key authentication. The prompt you are seeing is for the password for git, not the key password. That prompt would look like this: `Enter passphrase for key /Users/MYNAME/.ssh/id_rsa` though you don't have a passphrase set, so it will let you right in so long as you use the right commands.

The command to use key key authentication with ssh is:

`ssh user@hostname -i /location/to/private/key -p 8922`

Comment: thank you for your answer but even if I specify the path to the key I'm still asked to serve a password for the user git